# Specifying ELasticsearch's node.name in a docker-compose.yml

Tags: elasticsearch, docker-compose, dockerfile

The official [Elasticsearch docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/elasticsearch/) states that I can pass a flag/argument to set the node name:

```
$ docker run -d elasticsearch elasticsearch -Des.node.name="TestNode"
```

How can I specify this in my `docker-compose.yml`?

Answer (score 2):

`-Des.node.name="TestNode"` is just an argument to the command, so you would specify it as part of the `command`:

```
command: "elasticsearch -Des.node.name=TestNode"
```

You can also use the `entrypoint` as the "base" for command, and add args using `command`, like this:

```
entrypoint: elasticsearch
command: "-Des.node.name=TestNode"
```

If `ENTRYPOINT` is already set in the Dockerfile, you can omit it entirely.

Comment: Thanks but is there anyway I leave the `command` untouched? I don't want to override the original command in case they decided to change it for any reason! I mean if I'm trying to do `docker run` I can give the argument without changing the command, is it possible here to do the same?

Comment: It is but you would need to specify your own configuration file. Please have a look in too our docker image [million12/elasticsearch](https://hub.docker.com/r/million12/elasticsearch/)

Worth mentioning that our image is acting like an elasticsearch command. So whatever you want to specify during the process of run instead of using config files you can

Comment: I've added more information about `entrypoint` to my answer, which does what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to the `environment` section of a `docker-compose.yml` file, like so:

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=<your-node-name-here>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
environment:
      node.name: your-node-name-here
```